# Win32_PointingDevice fails to list touchscreens

Tags: powershell, screen, wmi, tablet

Im using Win 8 OS.The MSDN [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394356(v=vs.85).aspx) on `Win32_PointingDevice` mentions that `PointingType` will list 8 if you have a touch screen.
When running Powershell command

```
GET-WMIOBJECT WIN32_POINTINGDEVICE|SELECT CAPTION, POINTINGTYPE
```

It lists only the mouse devices.
How can I enumerate touch device details like the name that's shown on Control Panel using WMI

Comment: Where does your screen show up in device manager?

Comment: Under Device Manager>Monitors the touch screen is also listed. If I unplug it goes off. But DeviceManager>Mice and other pointing devices list only the HID-compliant mouse. The touch screen does work however